# Spring security: deny access to resource to specific role

Tags: spring, spring-security, roles

Im programming a collection of rest web services with Spring, but cant configure it with Spring security for certain logic.
I have these types of resources:

- Resources which can be accessed without being authenticated
- Resources accessible only to certain roles
- Resources NOT accessible to certain roles

I have a problem with the last requirement. I have tried the following:

```
        http
        .authorizeRequests()  
            .antMatchers("/resource1").permitAll()                
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resource2").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resource3").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resource4").not().hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().csrf().disable();
```

This code is the most similar to what I need:

- Everyone can access "resource1" even non-authenticated users
- Only roles USER and ADMIN can access resource2
- Only roles ADMIN can access resource3

BUT, the problem is on "resource4"... if the user is authenticated, everything works fine (only users without any role USER can access the resource)... the problem is that Spring permits access to **non-authentitcated users** (as I suppose it considers they don't belong to the rule USER, which is correct)

Any idea on how to configure a resource as not being accessible for certain roles, BUT having to be authenticated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use `.access(String expression)` it allows specifying that URLs are secured by an arbitrary expression

with expression = **"not( hasRole('USER') ) and isAuthenticated()"**

resulting in

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()  
        .antMatchers("/resource1").permitAll()                
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resource2").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resource3").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/resource4").access("not( hasRole('USER') ) and isAuthenticated()")
```